# having difficulty in getting api key and other relevant information in firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I just started with firebase and I am having some difficulty in getting api keys and other relevant data required.I am building a web app .
Here is the screenshot of the current screen that i got in firebase .
I clicked on Add project .Got directed to another page where I clicked on Develop ,then database and finally created a realtime database .But i am stuck as how to get relevant api key and other data .
I am following this tutorial
[tutorial link](https://blog.bitsrc.io/building-a-todo-app-in-react-with-firebase-and-redux-ba3ab53a671b)
 to get my hands on firebase and react.[image]

Comment: Are you looking for these Details of your project?? apiKey,authDomain,databaseURL,projectId,storageBucket,messagingSenderId Details??

Comment: Exactly .This is what I am looking for right now .@Fire-In-D-Hole

Comment: @godfather_satyajeet Posted with the screenshots .Hope that helps!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are new to Firebase so I'm going to Help you with the screenshots. As Tomka mentioned please read the documentation where it covers all the required information.

1-Go to Console, Select your project(In My Case TestApp)
[image]

2-After you have selected the Project, **Select Project Settings**
[image]

3-As you are configuring in the **Web app** (React), Please click the one pointed in the image.
[image]

4-You should have the Details you are looking for something like below
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the clear walkthrough! You should also have a "Add web app" link on the screen that you see when you click "Project Overview". The result is the same, but it's one less click. :)